# Why TypeScript does not complain when trying to read from never in an union type?

Tags: typescript

I thought that `TypeScript` would complain when trying to read the property `length` of what could be an `array` or `never`, and then, that I would need to narrow down the type with a type predicate. This is not the case. Why ? How could I change the types so TypeScript force me to check that I am not dealing with an empty object ?

```
// strictNullChecks = true
type Empty = Record<string, never>;

type NonEmpty = {
  documents: Array<number>;
};

function isEmpty(x: Empty | NonEmpty): x is Empty {
  return !("documents" in x);
}

const count = (x: Empty | NonEmpty) => {
  // TypeScript does not complain about reading `length` property of `never`
  // if (isEmpty(x)) {
  //   return 0;
  // }
  return x.documents.length;
};
```

Comment: Both empty and non empty are similar types and Empty type allows string as record keys where as NonEmpty defines it's keys in a more concrete fashion, since x.document is valid for a Record<string,never> and also in the union you say that document is an Array<number> so it treats x.document as such. In my opinion this is the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Below is a step by step type destruction example:

```
type Empty = Record<string, never>;

type NonEmpty = {
  documents: Array<number>;
};

function isEmpty(x: Empty | NonEmpty): x is Empty {
  return !("documents" in x);
}

const count = (x: Empty | NonEmpty) => {

  type D0 = typeof x.documents
  type D1 =  (Empty | NonEmpty)[`documents`]
  type D2 = Empty[`documents`] | NonEmpty[`documents`]
  type D3 =  never | NonEmpty[`documents`]
  type D4 =  NonEmpty[`documents`]
  type D5 =  Array<number>

  return x.documents.length; // x.documents is number[], that's why no error here
};
```

### And below is the expected behaviour example that may fit your need:

```
type EmptyExpected = Record<string, undefined>;

const countExpected = (x: EmptyExpected | NonEmpty) => {

  type D0 = typeof x.documents
  type D1 =  (EmptyExpected | NonEmpty)[`documents`]
  type D2 = EmptyExpected[`documents`] | NonEmpty[`documents`]
  type D3 =  undefined | NonEmpty[`documents`]
  type D4 =  undefined | number[]

  return x.documents.length; // x.documents is number[] | undefined, that's why it is an error here
};
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=31&ssc=1&pln=32&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAogtmUUC8UBKEDGB7ATgEwB4BnYXASwDsBzAGikogDcJcA+AbgCgvRIoActkrxEIFFADeXKFHzZMAVzgRKwYgC4oAQVy4AhiEKVlAI1acuAX25cAZosqZg5YVHLFRoABQAPLV7iAD6CwoEAlFq+7sSwCEjSsrgQwIq4lFAAhN4ARPJKKmrEOe4ZvuHcVjw4lKRQOI7AEn4B8cGhIm3hKGxSPLJ80AAiAAwSg9h2UL4AdPnKquoyUINQQwCMElDegVAhQp1i4QDaAAbzheqnALrLq0MATBKBZxeLxDd7HS-nCgtFNzu4GGAGYtowWLgvgcfm8AbcBsC1gAWLYwtqvP6XD4IlZIoYAVi2ugMRhMcHM7H6UGSqXS0zmWPeMwANqpqMAABYcKAAel5DLh6hiDDMrGO13oXP0wAA5LEAO6c8SUbBQVi4PBQTmsCDWWyrQIwXyQZwQfASDA4AgkMhUOhQRz4CB2KjmyxcGp1BpqY2m4Dm5r+OJiP1YAMW-ZhLo9PpA-ijcbAyaCplFePDTaobZGk3hwNRw6gE6-ArvQGIhNPVC5-3mzFl+HQ6NiBv-K64+5g7NOl1uyPfDGl9s4jMora912MAfkykS6m0tJlRmN9Ss9lcnn81Or2IeUUU8XXL6T-tSzky+VQJXichNff6DIarU65L6oA)

Answer (score 2):

Never gets dropped from union types (e.g. 0 + 5 = 5).

`type Test1 = never | string // string`

Never overrides other types in intersection types. (e.g. 0 x 5 = 0)

`type Test2 = never & string // never`

Docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type